# TypeError: string indices must be integers dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having trouble with python dictionaries. I have a dictionary of dictionaries that I am trying to obtain information from. The issue is that the same piece of code works for accessing a key called 'Scheduled' but doesn't work when I try to access a key called 'years'.

Anytime I try to access the key 'years' it returns this error
TypeError: string indices must be integers

The dictionary full of dictionaries is shown below

```
for entry in flight_history:
    Scheduled_Dictionary = entry['time']['scheduled']
    Scheduled_departure_date = Scheduled_Dictionary['departure_date']
    Aircraft_age = entry['aircraft']['age']['years]
```

```
{   'aircraft': {   'age': {   'availability': True,
                                   'date': 'Jan 1990',
                                   'days': 24,
                                   'months': 11,
                                   'testflight': False,
                                   'years': 30},
                        'availability': {'age': True, 'serialNo': True},
                        'country': {   'alpha2': 'GB',
                                       'alpha3': 'GBR',
                                       'name': 'United Kingdom'},
                        'model': {'code': 'SF34', 'text': 'Saab 340B'},
                        'registration': 'G-LGNF',
                        'restricted': False,
                        'serialNo': '340B-192'},

        'time': {   'estimated': {'arrival': 'None', 'departure': 'None'},
                    'other': {   'duration': 1980,
                                 'eta': 1577460761,
                                 'eta_date': '20191227',
                                 'eta_millis': 1577460761000,
                                 'eta_time': '1532',
                                 'updated': 1577460819,
                                 'updated_date': '20191227',
                                 'updated_millis': 1577460819000,
                                 'updated_time': '1533'},
                    'real': {   'arrival': 1577460761,
                                'arrival_date': '20191227',
                                'arrival_millis': 1577460761000,
                                'arrival_time': '1532',
                                'departure': 1577458777,
                                'departure_date': '20191227',
                                'departure_millis': 1577458777000,
                                'departure_time': '1459'},
                    'scheduled': {   'arrival': 1577457900,
                                     'arrival_date': '20191227',
                                     'arrival_millis': 1577457900000,
                                     'arrival_time': '1445',
                                     'departure': 1577455200,
                                     'departure_date': '20191227',
                                     'departure_millis': 1577455200000,
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem with the code and data given (although I did have to add a missing `'` on the last line of your code).

Comment: I found the error that dictionary full of dictionaries actually changes each time I iterate through my program. There is one record where the key ‘name’ isn’t actually present which causes that error.